# write a trigger on the task object to restrict the users not to delete the tasks whose case status is escalated

Tags: trigger

```
trigger NewTask4 on Task (before delete) {

List<Case> Cases =[select id, CaseNumber, Status from Case where Status= 
'Escalated'];
    For(Case C:Cases){
    for(Task t1:Trigger.old){
        
            if(C.Status== 'Escalated'){
                t1.addError('Task cant be deleted where case status  escalated');
            }
            else{
                delete t1;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
  }
```

It's working but whenever I am deleting the other task, it's showing a trigger error.if i am trying to delete the task which connected  to case , it s properly working but , when i am trying to delete another task which is not connected to case also not deleting , showing same validation error

Comment: Please share the error and more detals

Comment: Please update your code properly. Some is not in code format and it is headache to read

Comment: sorry now u can see

Comment: Since you are in a trigger for deletion, there's no need to have the `else { delete t1 }`. Indeed, this is going to cause an exception that will actually block the deletion of t1, since t1 is already in the process of being deleted.

Answer (score 1):

In the query you are querying all the case with escalated and you are not using WHATID as task and case are related to each other using WhatId field.

You need to check on the task if the task is related to case or not and add it to the set as below.

```
set<id> caseid= new set<id>();
    for(Task t:Trigger.old){
        String whatid=t.WhatId;
        if(whatid.startsWith(Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix())){
            caseid.add(t.WhatId);
        }
    }
```

You can use the below logic to check if the case status is esclated and add the error based on it.

```
map<id,Case> casesById = new map<id,Case>([select id, CaseNumber, Status from Case where Status= 'Escalated' and id in :caseid]); 
    system.debug('map element'+mapcase);
    for(Task ts:Trigger.old){
        if(casesById.containsKey(ts.WhatId)){
            ts.addError('Task cant be deleted where case status  escalated');
 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hard coding ID prefixes is a hack. You can easily derive the prefix using `Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix`. Better, this works for standard and custom SObject types. I would also make sure you name variables more clearly. Your map, `mapcase`, would be better called `casesById` which tells you the values are Cases and the keys are IDs.

Comment: @PhilW, Thanks for your suggestion . I have noted those points and modified the answer based on it.